# Prev, Next & Close buttons won't show

Tags: button, lightbox

First timer here, I installed Lightbox and it is running brilliantly.

Buttons are not visible normally, but when i hover the where it should be, buttons becomes visible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your lightbox.css file. By default Lightbox hides the controls. In the css you will see lines where the opacity is set to zero. So what you might be looking for is something like the following.

```
.lb-prev, .lb-next {
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0); //change to  100%
opacity: 0; //change to  100%
}
```

Since you say you say your a first timer I would recommend going through the CSS file and where you see something recarding the opacity change it saved it and check what it did, till you get the result you want.